# Rally - Filter Epics by Milestone Name

Tags: javascript, json, rally

Is it possible to filter a PortfolioItem by using just the name of a Milestone? For example, how would I filter MMFs by using a Milestone tag name.

```
var mmfFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
        property : 'Milestone',
        operator : '=', 
        value : milestoneName // String of the name of the milestone tag
    });

    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'PortfolioItem/MMF', 
        autoLoad: true,                      
        filters : mmfFilter,
        listeners: {
            load: function(myStore, myData, success) {
                console.log('MMFs with this milestone tag name', myData); // prints null

            },
            scope: this                         
        },
        fetch: ['CreationDate','FormattedID', 'Name', 'Parent']
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can!  Milestones is a collection, so you may need to use the contains operator, but something like this should work:

```
{
    property: 'Milestones.Name',
    operator: '=', //or maybe 'contains'?
    value: milestoneName
}
```

In general you can drilldown into object properties in query filters using the dot syntax.